# Do I need an apostrophe in this title?

Tags: grammar, apostrophe

**Educations Influence on Christianity**

This is the title of my essay. Does 'educations' need an apostrophe?

Comment: Hi Ariel, welcome to ELU. Your question is a bit basic for this site (the answer is you *do* need an apostrophe, because you're talking about *the influence **of** education* on Christianity), but it would probably be better asked on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: How many educations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you want to use that title, it should be **Education's Influence on Christianity**. However, some publications don't like apostrophes in titles, and they might suggest a rewording to something a little more pompous-sounding, such as **The Influence of Education on Christianity**. You could also try being more active: **How Education has Influenced Christianity**, for example.

Comment: "How Education has Influenced Christianity" would be my vote.  That sounds much more interesting to me.